# How to use gradle in intellij idea plugin project?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-plugin

I am developing an idea plugin, and it is an intellij idea project.

I want to use gradle to manage the dependency.

How to config?

Comment: From the menu: File -> New project -> choose Gradle ->...

Comment: It's not as simple as that. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a [Gradle plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin) for building IntelliJ Platform Plugins. In order to use it, you will need to add the following snippet to your `build.gradle` file.

```
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.0.31"
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
```

For more information, please see [this guide](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/build_system/prerequisites.html) to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are multiple ways to create an IntelliJ project, "templates" if you like, and unfortunately you can only pick one of them (*IntelliJ plugin* or *gradle*).

Thankfully, it's easy to configure a project for gradle in IntelliJ.

First, create a new project from the `IntelliJ Platform Plugin` template. You don't need to choose any *Additional Libraries and Frameworks*. This will give you a project structure including `META-INF/plugin.xml` and the `Project SDK` should be something like `IDEA IU-129.451`.

From here, simply create a new file named `build.gradle` at the top level of your project, including for example this line:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Now, close the project. You can now use `File` -> `Import Project...`, choose the `build.gradle` file that you just created, and import the project. Accept the defaults for importing and hit *OK*.

The project is now opened with both gradle and intellij plugin enabled!

Notice that the source root `src` has disappeared and you will need to right click on `src` in the Project pane and select `Mark Directory As` -> `Source Root`.

To prepare the plugin for deployment, there is still the menu option in the `Build` menu for that - if you want to automate that part via gradle, good luck and please let us know how it's done ;)